# How to template'ize variable NAMES, not types?

Tags: c++, templates

my question is about how to template'ize the ***name*** of a class member that should be used.

Maybe a simplified & pseudo example:

```
/** 
Does something with a specified member of every element in a List.
*/
template<membername MEMBER> // <-- How to define such thing?
void doSomething(std::vector<MyClass> all){

    for( i=0; i < all.size(); i++)
      all[i].MEMBER++; // e.g.; use all[i].MEMBER in same way

}
```

and

```
class MyClass{
public:
    int aaa, bbb, ccc;
}
```

and the application:

```
main(){
    vector<MyClass> all = ....

    // applicate doSomething() to all aaa's
    doSomething<aaa>(all);  // or:
    doSomething<MyClass::aaa>(all); // or:
    doSomething<?????>(all);
}
```

How should the template definition looks like, that I can switch which member variable (aaa, bbb or ccc) of MyClass is accessed/modified in doSomething(.) ?
In my real world task all MEMBER are of same type, as above.

Thanks,
Tebas

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Template parameters are restricted to types, integer constants, pointers/references to functions or objects with external linkage *and member pointers* -- but no identifiers.

But you could use a member pointer as template parameter:

```
template<int MyClass::* MemPtr>
void doSomething(std::vector<MyClass> & all) {
   for( i=0; i < all.size(); i++)
      (all[i].*MemPtr)++;
}

:

doSomething<&MyClass::aaa>(all);
```

Note that I changed the *doSomething* function to take a reference instead of accepting the vector by value.

Comment: Thanks. 
Call 'all' by value was for simplification of the question ... but is call by reference requested by member pointer templates? or can i also use a copy?

Comment: @Tebas: You can use a copy, but that means the effect of `doSomething` will not be visible outside the function. Call by reference was used to ensure the result would be visible in the caller's vector.

Comment: @Tebas: No, it doesn't make any difference. In either case all[i] will be an lvalue expression of type MyClass.

Comment: Too bad that there can't be a member pointer to a data-member of reference type, and that member pointers can't be used to catch a set of overloaded functions or a function template :( Someone on usenet lately proposed "name" template parameters that would make this possible. I liked the proposal.

Answer (score 10):

sellibitze's solution is fine (though to be honest not very: see my edit), only it limits you to using only members of type int. A more general solution would be this (although the member is NOT a template parameter here)

```
#include <vector>

struct MyClass
{
   int i;
   char c;
};

template <class T>
void DoSomething(std::vector<MyClass>& all, T MyClass::* MemPtr)
{ 
   for(std::vector<MyClass>::size_type i = 0; i < all.size(); ++i)
      (all[i].*MemPtr)++;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<MyClass> all;
   DoSomething(all, &MyClass::i);
   DoSomething(all, &MyClass::c);
}
```

EDIT:
Also please note that it is not generally a good idea for a pointer to member to be a template parameter inasmuch as ***only such pointers that are known compile-time can be passed***, that is you can't determine the pointer runtime and then pass it as a template param.

Comment: `vector::all()` returns `size_t` and not `unsigned` - please use `size_t` for `i`. (Iterators would be even better…)

Comment: @Steve: I totally agree about the iterators, I just copied the text from  op's code. I won't change that. and size() does NOT return size_t, it returns std::vector<MyClass>::size_type. And what is vector::all? :D

Comment: Oops, you are correct on point 1 and I don't know what I was thinking on point 2. +1 for you. Oddly enough, I *just answered* a question related to vectors and knew to use `size_type` and not `size_t`. Sometimes I am bad.

Answer (score 1):

I would use lambdas to solve this problem. Something like this:

```
#include <vector>     // vector
#include <algorithm>  // for_each
#include <functional> // function

struct MyClass {
   void func1() const { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
   void func2() const { std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

void doSomething(std::vector<MyClass> all, std::function<void (MyClass& m)> f)
{
   std::for_each(all.begin(), all.end(), f);
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<MyClass> all;
   all.push_back(MyClass());

    // apply various methods to each MyClass:
   doSomething(all, [](MyClass& m) { m.func1(); });
   doSomething(all, [](MyClass& m) { m.func2(); });
}
```

Of course in this case the function `doSomething` is unnecessary. I could just as simply call `for_each` directly on `all`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a bit old, but none of the answers use the method I have developed, and I would like to share it.

First, in C++ we typically are discouraged from directly accessing member variables and encouraged to provide setters/getters to help enforce hiding of information.

Second, while C++ goes a long way towards eliminating use of macros, they can still accomplish a lot of things that are difficult (or near impossible) with templates and classes.

The following uses a macro to create typed setters & getters for fields in a container member within a class:

```
//
// Bit(n) -- sets 'n'th bit.
//    Bit(0) == 0x1 (b0000001),
//    Bit(1) == 0x2 (b0000010),
//    Bit(2) == 0x4 (b0000100),
//    Bit(3) == 0x8 (b0001000), etc.
//
#define Bit(n)        (1 << (n))

//
// BitMask(n) -- creates mask consisting of 'n' bits.
//    BitMask(0) == 0x0 (b00000000),
//    BitMask(1) == 0x1 (b00000001),
//    BitMask(2) == 0x3 (b00000011),
//    BitMask(3) == 0x7 (b00000111), etc.
//
#define BitMask(n)    (Bit(n) - 1)

//
// BitRange(n, m) -- creates mask consisting of bits between n & m, inclusive.
//    BitRange(0, 3) == 0x0f (b00001111),
//    BitRange(2, 5) == 0x3c (b00111100),
//    BitRange(6, 1) == 0x7e (b01111110), etc.
//    
//
#define BitRange(n,m) (BitMask(n) ^ BitMask(m))

#define namedBitField(name, container, start, end, EnumType)                                      \
                              EnumType name() const                                               \
                                {return                                                           \
                                  (EnumType)                                                      \
                                    ((container & BitRange(start,end))                            \
                                      >> start);                                                  \
                                };                                                                \
                              void     name(EnumType v) {container |= (v << start);};             \

class myTest
{
  public:
    enum vSet1
    {
      a = 1,
      b = 2,
    };
  private:
    unsigned long holder;
  public:
    myTest() {};
    namedBitField(set1, holder, 0, 3, vSet1);
    namedBitField(set2, holder, 4, 5, vSet1);
};

myTest  mt;
```

The ***namedBitField()*** macro takes the ***name*** for the getter/setter pair, the target ***container*** -- ***holder*** in this example, the bitfield ***start***/***end***, and the ***EnumType*** that is to be used for values in the bitfield.

If I now use the setter/getter pairs named ***set1()*** & ***set2()*** in the above example, and attempt to pass POD (plain-old-data) numbers I will get a warning from the compiler.

```
mt.set1(22); // compiler warns here.
mt.set1();

mt.set2(myTest::vSet1::a); // no warnings.
mt.set2();
```

No, it is not a "typed bitfield", but it is the next best thing.

No, it is not quite as easy to use as defining bitfields in a struct, but this way you get strong typing via the setters/getters.

Now, you could define the bitfields in structs, make them private, and access them via setters/getters as well, but then the information about where the bits are located is separated from the setters/getters which logically *are* tied to that information, and as several responders above have pointed out, each C++ compiler can put the bits anywhere they want, so without looking at generated assembler -- or testing on hardware if you are brave -- you cannot be certain things are happening the way you want.

The way the setters/getters created by ***namedBitField()*** manipulate the bits in a well-defined order and guarantee bit-order within ***container***, so you can now use the code cross-platform for accessing I/O registers.

Note: in my example I use 'name' as both setter and getter with compiler sorting it out based on use.  Some may prefer 'get_name' and 'set_name'. YMMV.

Since the getters/setters are public, and as long as the things you are iterating all derive from the same base class, you can now iterate across the items in a vector -- as above -- and get type-safe getting/setting for the values used in the iteration.

Comment: Almost all of this could be done with functions and templates as well, with just one macro to create a final pair of functions.

Comment: I'm not really sure where you are going with this comment.  The Bit...() macros are just there to show the bit manipulation.  There is "just one macro" which creates the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trait-type class. Unlike `std::function` this operates at compile time and doesn't constrain the data you are acquiring.

```
#include <iostream>

class TheClass
{
public:
    int SOME_FIELD;
};

template<typename TClass, typename TTrait>
class TheTemplate
{
public:
    TClass Value;
    
    int WhatField()
    {
        return TTrait::GetField(Value);
    }
};

class TheTrait
{
public:
    static int GetField(TheClass& f)
    {
        return f.SOME_FIELD;
    }
};


int main() {
    TheTemplate<TheClass, TheTrait> theTemplate{TheClass{5}};
    std::cout << theTemplate.WhatField();
    return 0;
}
```