# set a specific member with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

let's say I have this:

```
    struct myStruct {
    int A;
    int B;
}
```

Is it possible to set a specific member via a template parameter like this?

```
void setTo10<?? member>(myStruct& obj) {
obj.member = 10;
}
```

//usage:

```
setTo10<"member A">(obj);
```

I know it's possible with a macro but how about a template?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942426/how-to-templateize-variable-names-not-types ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
struct myStruct {
  int A;
  int B;
};

template <typename T, typename V>
void set(T& t, V T::*f, V v)
{ t.*f = v; }

int main()
{
  myStruct m;
  set(m, &myStruct::A, 10);
  std::cout << m.A << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works and I'll accept it, but you are not actually passing &myStruct::A at compile-time right?

Comment: Right, this isn't a compile time parameter. However, since this function probably gets inlined, this can be easily optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

This solution allows to select a member via a compile-time index (which could be computed via another compile-time expression):

```
struct myStruct {
    int A;
    int B;
};

template <int n1, int n2>
struct SetOnEqual
{
    static void set(int& var, int val)
    {} // default: do nothing
};

template<int n>
struct SetOnEqual<n, n>
{
    static void set(int& var, int val)
    {
        var = val;
    }
};

template <int n>
void setTo10(myStruct& s)
{
    SetOnEqual<n,0>::set(s.A, 10);
    SetOnEqual<n,1>::set(s.B, 10);
}
```

Then the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    myStruct s;
    s.A = s.B = 0;

    setTo10<0>(s); // sets s.A
    printf("s=(%d,%d)\n", s.A, s.B);

    setTo10<1>(s); // sets s.B
    printf("s=(%d,%d)\n", s.A, s.B);

    return 0;
}
```

gives the output

```
s=(10,0)
s=(10,10)
```